# Default terminal changes are not applied to desktop launchers and nautilus-open-terminal

Tags: command-line, unity, gnome-terminal, lxterminal

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. The desktop environment is Unity.

I changed my default terminal to `lxterminal` in this way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16808639/5900630. Now, if I press `Ctrl`+`T`, `lxterminal` opens. Now I have

update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator 
There are 8 choices for the alternative x-terminal-emulator (providing /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator).

```
  Selection    Path                             Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/local/bin/lxterminal         70        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper   40        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/koi8rxterm               20        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/lxterm                   30        manual mode
  4            /usr/bin/lxterminal               40        manual mode
  5            /usr/bin/uxterm                   20        manual mode
  6            /usr/bin/xfce4-terminal.wrapper   40        manual mode
  7            /usr/bin/xterm                    20        manual mode
* 8            /usr/local/bin/lxterminal         70        manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

However, my desktop launchers that has `terminal=True` still open `gnome-terminal` when they launch. Also, if I right click on a Nautilus window, and choose "Open in Terminal" (feature supported by `nautilus-open-terminal`), `gnome-terminal` starts.

PS: Don't bother with that `/usr/bin/lxterminal` and `/usr/local/bin/lxterminal` stuff... The latter one is a modified version of `lxterminal` that supports different color scheme. It doesn't affect the launcher behavior because I observed this on both option (4 and  8).

Example launcher file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Icon[en_US]=gnome-panel-launcher
Exec=ssh -tt -p <port> <user>@<host> ssh -p <port> <user>@<host>
Name=<name>
Icon=utilities-terminal
```

How to change the behavior of launchers and `nautilus-open-terminal`?

Comment: This is exactly my question! Wish someone had answered it...